# Make custom request when auth session is expired or user logged out

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity-2

In one MVC project, I implemented asp.net identity based on cookies. Now I have a requirement to make a request to remote service when auth session is expired or when user logged off.

Is there any natural way to accomplish that? For now I managed to set two delegate properties from CookieAuthenticationProvider like below:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(expireInMinutes),
            CookiePath = cookiePath,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = c =>
                {
                    if (c.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue && c.Properties.ExpiresUtc.Value < c.Options.SystemClock.UtcNow)
                    {
                        c.RejectIdentity();
                        c.Request.Context.Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                    if (c.Options.SlidingExpiration)
                    {
                        // Reissue the auth cookie
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                OnResponseSignOut = c =>
                {
                    // Make a custom request
                }
            }
        });
```

At first glance it looks like it works but I don't like the idea of checking expiry date in here. Problem is that OnResponseSignOut is not called when auth cookie is simply expired but is called only when I explicitly call IAuthenticationManager.SignOut.

Is creating a custom CookieAuthenticationProvider the best option in here, or maybe there is another clean and natural solution for that case?

Comment: You'll always have a problem when user simply closes his browser without logging-out (or pulls power cord out from his PC) - you'll never know when this happens and no way to do anything about it.

Comment: Thats a true story.